# Oracle return part of CLOB string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm looking to siphon-out a part of the string stored in a CLOB on an Oracle SQL db.

Example:

```
<option id="862111" ncTypeId="338" ncPopup="true" ncLabel="{Q}: {A}" score="0" action="none" tooltip="This is an example tooltip string.">Red</option>
```

Essentially, I want to retain only the text held within the string that the tooltip element refers to, ending up with:

This is an example tooltip string

How can this be achieved please?

Comment: Don't understand your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Essentially, everything contained within the tooltip"" part of the string, remove everything else

Comment: Is that whole line stored in the BLOB? I thought it was a page rendering or something.

Comment: Closest I've got is with:


SELECT NVL(SUBSTR(my_col, 0, INSTR(my_col, 'tooltip=')-1), my_col) AS output
  FROM my_table;

But that just returns the first N characters, ignoring the inputs

Comment: Yes, the whole line - it's XML stored as a CLOB datatype

Answer (score 1):

If it's XML stored as a CLOB then use XML functions:

```
-- CTE for your sample value
with my_table (my_col) as (
  select to_clob('<option id="862111" ncTypeId="338" ncPopup="true" ncLabel="{Q}: {A}" score="0" action="none" tooltip="This is an example tooltip string.">Red</option>')
  from dual
)
-- actual query
select xmlquery('/option/@tooltip'
  passing xmltype(my_col)
  returning content)
  .getStringVal() as tooltip
from my_table;

TOOLTIP                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is an example tooltip string.
```

Read more about [the XMLQuery() function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html).

If you want to use substr/instr then you need to find the starting position inside the quotes, and the length of the value in the quotes, which is a little bit messy (and you need to handle that attribute not existing at all):

```
select substr(my_col, instr(my_col, 'tooltip="') + 9,
  instr(substr(my_col, instr(my_col, 'tooltip="') + 9), '"') - 1) as tooltip
from my_table;

TOOLTIP                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is an example tooltip string.
```

You could also use a regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace(my_col, '.*tooltip="(.*)".*', '\1') as tooltip
from my_table;
```

but I imagine that won't perform that well; but you should test all the available approaches to see which performs best with your data.

Comment: Legend! Thank you so much!